# Bessel function expansion with complex argument

Tags: bessel-functions

In "Bessel function of the first kind with complex argument" paper, authors have expanded a Bessel function $$ J_0(z) $$ with complex argument $$ z=x+i y $$ for $$ |x|\ll 1 $$ and $$ |y|\ll 1. $$ But I want to expand it when $$ |y|\gg|x| $$ or $$|y|\ll|x|$$. Now I am confused that the result of the mentioned article is right for $$ |y|\gg|x| or |y|\ll|x|$$ or not?
Please help me!!!!!!!!

Comment: What paper?  Authors, journal, date?  Can you give us a link to that paper?

Comment: Dear Robert, its link is: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010465597000878